# How to create a HSQL in-memory-db from script file?

Tags: java, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I have two HSQL databases in memory. With the first database I create the database structure and test data which is time-consuming. This database is exported via the `SCRIPT` command into a sql file. My second database (not necessarily in the same JVM) should be build from that exported sql file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (Connection firstConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:connection1", "sa", "")) {
        try (Statement statement = firstConnection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute("CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT)");
            statement.execute("SCRIPT 'my.script'");
        }
    }

    try (Connection secondConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:connection2", "sa", "")) {
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(secondConnection, new FileSystemResource("my.script"));
    }
}
```

When invoking `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript()` I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: invalid authorization specification - already exists: SA in statement [CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e']
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(JDBCUtil.java:327)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(JDBCUtil.java:247)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(JDBCStatement.java:1817)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(JDBCStatement.java:638)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:457)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid authorization specification - already exists: SA
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:83)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Error.java:72)
    at org.hsqldb.rights.GranteeManager.addUser(GranteeManager.java:623)
    at org.hsqldb.rights.UserManager.createUser(UserManager.java:115)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.getResult(StatementSchema.java:1026)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementSchema.execute(StatementSchema.java:268)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Session.java:1378)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Session.java:1248)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Session.java:1008)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(JDBCStatement.java:1809)
    ... 5 more
```

What is the correct way to export an existing in-memory-database and import it later into another (empty) in-memory-database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCRIPT statements creates a full database script that can be opened as a file database. Open the second database as a file: database that does not store the modifications.

```
Connection secondConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:my;files_readonly=true", "sa", "")
```

Comment: I chose this solution for the moment, but I'm still hoping for a better one.

Comment: A `better` solution is which way?

Comment: I copied the original script file to a temp directory and created an instance of that copied file because I need a writable version which can be thrown away. "Better" (for myself) would be a mem: database and the database should not be readonly, so I can tell HSQL "hey, make me a mem: database out of this script file (backup)".

Comment: You got it wrong. Only the database `FILES` are readonly. The data can be modified. The files are not modified after initial loading. It is equivalent to a mem: database, but loaded from a script.

Answer (score -1):

The problem appear to be with the script not the code running it.

The error is that its attempting to create the SA user `CREATE USER SA` which already exists (its the user you've authenticated with to run the script in the first place).

You should be remove (comment out) that line in the script and you should then be able to progress further.

Comment: If I comment out the `CREATE USER SA` I get the next error. If I comment out that line I continue to another error and so on. There should be a way to export a database and import it without additional modifications.